# In JIRA Classic Task Board, is there a way to filter for multiple assignees?

Tags: jira

In JIRA Classic Task Board, there is a feature to filter by any assignee.

But I would like to see three assignees at the same time.

is there a way to filter for multiple assignees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQL such as: assignee in (bob, joe, steve)